# Ignoring strings that i dont want to copy in a text file

Tags: c, linux, file

Suppose I have a list of ip that i don't want to copy in a text file. Here's what i do..
For example i don't want to copy `192.168.5.20.`..

In my temp.txt file i have ip's:

```
192.168.5.20
192.168.5.10
192.168.5.30
192.168.5.50
192.168.5.12
```

-

```
char *data = "192.168.5.20";

char buff[100];
FILE *in, *out;

in = fopen("/tmp/temp.txt", "r");

while(fgets(buff,sizeof(buff),in) !=NULL){


        if(!strstr(buff, data)){

        printf("copying to ip.txt\n");
        out = fopen("/tmp/ip.txt", "a");
        fprintf(out,"%s",buff);
        fclose(out);
        }


}
if(feof(in)){

printf("Closing file descriptor and renaming ip.txt to temp.txt\n");
fclose(in);
rename("/tmp/ip.txt", "/tmp/temp.txt");
}
```

It work's leaving `192.168.5.20` ip.. but my problem is when temp.txt have only one ip..
e.g `192.168.5.20`

Now i want to ignore it so when i open up my temp.txt file it should be blank. but still ip `192.168.5.20` is there when i open up my temp.txt file?.. Why is it doing that?.

Thanks..

Comment: Of course not, there's no `/tmp/ip.txt`.

Comment: Sorry about that. just modified it..Yes it does succeed in renaming the ip.txt to temp.txt.. but still when i run it i still get 192.168.5.20 in temp.txt

Comment: To get thing done, you can use `grep -v PATTERN file`

Comment: What does grep -v PATTERN file does?.. thanks

Comment: Thanks all i got it working.. Daniel Fischer thanks didn't notice that ip.txt is not being created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file `/tmp/ip.txt` is only created when there is at least one line in `/tmp/temp.txt` that doesn't contain the pattern to be ignored.

```
if(!strstr(buff, data)){
    printf("copying to ip.txt\n");
    out = fopen("/tmp/ip.txt", "a");
    fprintf(out,"%s",buff);
    fclose(out);
}
```

So if `/tmp/temp.txt` contains only one line, and that contains the pattern to be ignored, no `/tmp/ip.txt` is created, and `rename` fails, setting `errno` to `ENOENT`.

Check that with

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

int fail = rename("/home/dafis/Doesntexist", "/home/dafis/doesexist");
if (fail) {
    int en = errno;
    if (en)
        perror(strerror(en));
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.. I didn't noticed that ip.txt is not being created.

Answer (score 0):

If there is only `192.168.5.20` in the file temp.txt, you are not even entering the while loop. That means you are not opening (creating if not existing) ip.txt. So rename fails and temp.txt remains the same.
You can try changing your code as following

```
   if (feof(in))
   {
      if(0 == out)
         out = fopen("ip.txt", "a");
      printf("\nrename returned %d",rename("ip.txt", "temp.txt"));

      printf("Closing file descriptor and renaming ip.txt to temp.txt\n");
      fclose(in);
   }
```

Do add some NULL checks in the code. Saves precious time.

Answer (score 0):

```
char *unwanted = "192.168.5.20";

char buff[100];
FILE *in, *out;
unsigned cnt;

in = fopen("/tmp/temp.txt", "r");
out = fopen("/tmp/ip.txt", "w");

if (!in || !out) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

for (cnt=0; fgets(buff,sizeof buff,in) ; ){
        if(strstr(buff, unwanted)) continue;
        fprintf(out,"%s",buff);
        cnt++;
        }

fclose(out);
fclose(in);

 /* note: this will maintain the original file if it **only** consists
 ** of lines with the (unwanted) pattern in it.
 ** IMHO you'd better do the rename unconditionally; an empty file
 ** would be the correct result if all the lines match.
 */
if(cnt){ 
    printf("Closing file descriptor and renaming ip.txt to temp.txt\n");
    rename("/tmp/ip.txt", "/tmp/temp.txt");
    }
```